# In PHP what is the equivalent of C#'s RNGCryptoServiceProvider?

Tags: php, cryptography, rngcryptoserviceprovider

I'm studying basic security for asp.net and php, I was already able to implement the application on asp.net now what I want to do is come up with the same thing using php

Here is the code that I'm using for my asp.net application that I want to convert to php if it's possible:

```
public static byte[] GenerateSalt()
    {
        const int MinSaltSize = 4;
        const int MaxSaltSize = 8;

        // Generate a random number to determine the salt size.
        Random random = new Random();
        int saltSize = random.Next(MinSaltSize, MaxSaltSize);

        // Allocate a byte array, to hold the salt.
        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[saltSize];

        // Initialize the cryptographically secure random number generator.
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

        // Fill the salt with cryptographically strong byte values.
        rng.GetNonZeroBytes(saltBytes);

        return saltBytes;
    }
```

I would also like to know what function to use for rng.GetNonZeroBytes() in php

Then I would use base64_encode/base64_decode for the data. Sir/Ma'am your answers would be of great help. Thank you++ :D

Comment: Random salt size is weird. no reason to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mcrypt_create_iv(size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php) should be OK, despite the weird name. It's pretty much equivalent to `rng.GetBytes`.

Using `DEV_URANDOM` is essential, `DEV_RANDOM` is *very slow* for a negligible increase in security, and `RAND` is insecure.

Not sure why you'd want non-zero bytes. After Base64 encoding the zero-bytes will be normal printable characters.

I recommend using something like `base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(9, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM))`

Comment: Thank you for the immediate reply I would just like to know what is the meaning of 9 in the parameters. Thank you++  :D

Comment: The size of the salt in bytes. The standard recommendation is to use at least 64 bit salts. 9 meets that recommendation, and since it's a multiple of three the Base64 encoding doesn't add any useless padding.

Answer (score 0):

mcrypt_create_iv is depreciated and removed after PHP 7.2.0
Now that you can use:

echo base64_encode(random_bytes(9));